# How to set predefined screen Resoloution ( Display screen not connected )

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, vnc

I use Ubuntu MATE +Raspberry Pi 3.

While RPI is connected to an external display via HDMI, resolution is adapted automatically to screen res.
BUT when ext. screen is not connected ( remote control via VNC ), screen res probably takes a default\ minimal res - 720X480.

How can I define a default res to be 1920X1080 if no ext display is detected ?